# I can run Get-ADuser on a machine that does NOT have RSAT installed. How is this possible?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to run Powershell Get-Aduser on a new PC and when it did not run, installing RSAT Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Services Tools fixed the issue.
HOWEVER, I have another PC that does NOT have the same RSAT installed and I can run Get-Aduser in powershell with no issue.
I am logging into each machine with the same AD user on each machine.

Summary:
Two PCs, NEITHER has RSAT, same domain user, but one PC can run Get-ADUser, the other can not.
How is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: You may have different versions of PS installed.

Comment: Use  `(Get-Command Get-ADUser).Module` to determine the originating module. Note that you question is better suited to [su].

Answer (score 0):

Get-AdUser is a cmdlet offered in the ActiveDirectory PowerShell module, and possibly others. As mklement0 notes you can see which module it is available from by running the command `(Get-Command Get-ADUser).Module`

How that has been made available or imported in your PowerShell profile will depend on other factors, including being pushed by organization policy.